TLG support for BOOST questions
Some of you may have noticed that I've posted and self-answered a couple of BOOST questions recently. As our LEGO Ambassador, I'm trying out something new. TLG has provided me with a BOOST set in order to help us to better answer questions about that product, and I'm trying to get a few basic questions up in the hopes that more questions from users will be coming soon.
I'm hoping that we can do more of this sort of thing in the future, but I wanted to be the first of us to try it out both for simplicity and so that I can report back directly to TLG.
If you have ideas for other sets or products that might be helpful in the future, I'm open to suggestions. BOOST seemed like a logical place to start as it's likely to generate a lot of questions going forward.

I think the Boost is interesting but there are too many limitations for me to considering buying one, particularly in comparison to the EV3. Hopefully we see some interesting questions and lots of creativity.

I agree completely. For an adult, EV3 has so much more depth than BOOST. BOOST does seem to be much simpler and I could see a younger kid having fun with it.

I'm rather curious about Spike too; and there seems to be a lot of concern in general about the new powered up elements and interaction - especially about compatibility, running stuff without apps, and future obsolescence. Guess I should start firing a few questions of my own

@Joubarc I'm interested in this as well. I have some Powered Up elements, but not Spike or the new Technic Control+ hub. I'll certainly try to answer any questions that I can. I recently changed jobs, so I haven't had a ton of time for LEGO, but hopefully I'll find a good rhythm and have more leisure time soon. :)

I've got boost 17101 and it quickly gets boring after building all five creations and I think it's too childish. 31313 is much better imo because you can build over 30 different creations with it (yes, that includes MOCs) and it's more dynamic. So don't expect any Boost questions.
